# RegEx: Match Non-Escaped Double Quoted Strings

Tags: php, html, regex, escaping, syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a Ruby code box with syntax highlighting (for Ruby) written in php for my website, I can get it to color instance variables, comments, symbols and global variables so far but I have encountered a problem when using the following regex to match double quoted strings, here is my code:

```
<?php
    function codebox($code, $name="", $highlighted_line = -1)
    {   

        echo '<table class="code_table">';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="code_table_header"></td>';
        echo '<td class="code_table_name">$name</td>';
        echo '<td class="code_table_header"><a href="" class="copy_to_clipboard_link">copy to clipboard</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

        $oddity = 'even';
        $line_number = 1;
        foreach(preg_split('/(\r?\n)/', $code) as $line)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            if($line_number % 10 == 0)
            {
                echo '<td class="line_number" style="font-weight:bold;">' . $line_number . '</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td class="line_number">' . $line_number . '</td>';
            }
            if($line_number == $highlighted_line)
            {
                echo '<td class="selected_code_cell" colspan="2">' . syntax_highlight($line) . '</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td class="' . $oddity . '_code_cell" colspan="2">' . syntax_highlight($line) . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
            $line_number += 1;
            if($oddity == 'even')
            {
                $oddity = 'odd';
            } else {
                $oddity = 'even';
            };
        };
    };
    function syntax_highlight($code)
    {
        // Make it so html doesn't bodge up
        $code = htmlentities($code);

        // Replace tabs with 4 none blocking spaces
        $code = str_replace('   ', '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $code);

        //instance variables
        $code = preg_replace('/\B(\@\w*\S)/', '<span style="color:lime;">$1</span>', $code);

        //global variables
        $code = preg_replace('/\B(\$\w*\S)/', '<span style="font-weight:bolder;color:#00b0f0;">$1</span>', $code);

        //symbols
        $code = preg_replace('/\B(\:\w*\S)/', '<span style="color:yellow;">$1</span>', $code);

        //strings (double quote)
        $code = preg_replace('/"(?:\.|(\\\")|[^\""\n])*"/', '<span style="font-style:italic;color:#FF5A00;">$1</span>', $code);

        //strings (single quote)
        //$code = preg_replace('/\'(?:\.|(\\\')|[^\'\'\n])*\'/', '<span style="font-style:italic;color:#FF5A00;">$1</span>', $code);

        return $code;
    };
?>
```

For some reason, the double quoted string breaks the other ones and no syntax highlighting is performed, does anyone know why? Thanks in advance, ell.

Comment: Are you sure you should be capturing the double and single quotes only? That's what the regexes indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t try to parse an irregular language like Ruby with regular expressions. Try to find a proper parser for Ruby instead that returns an array of the used language tokens.

Comment: Why not? Modern patterns are not the primitive things restricted to regular languages as taught in finite automata courses. I'm not saying that you *should* use patterns for everything like this, mind you; grabbing the tokenizer’s output is obviously a much better approach. But the limitations of computability as taught in automata courses have virtually no relevance to modern patterns, which have backreferences, conditionals, recursion, and much more.

Comment: @tchrist: Using regular expressions for irregular languages might work with nowadays regular expression implementations. But it is far more complex, error prone, and probably inefficient than using a parser.

Comment: With the proviso that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044946/regex-to-split-html-tags/4045840#4045840) is intended as an example of why using regular expressions instead of parsers may be a bad idea, I’m not sure that that is inherently more complex, error prone, or inefficient than a parser. In fact, it **is** a parser, wouldn’t you agree?

Answer (score 0):

What Gumbo said. You cannot make this work correctly with regular expressions alone. But you might try this:

```
 preg_match("/'([^'\n\\]|\\'|\\[^'])+'/", ...
```

Or maybe you have better luck with an assertion `(?<![\\])` right before the quote.