# PHP preg_match_all() not capturing subgroups

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to parse a Twitter atom feed in PHP but am running into this strange issue. I'm calling [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with this regexp string:

```
"|<entry>.*<title>(.*)</title>.*<published>(.*)</published>.*</entry>|xsU"
```

It matches all the entries OK, but the captured subgroups title/published do not show up in the results (no arrays for the captured subgroups are created in the result object).

Now to the strange part, I try to capture the last bit as well:

```
"|<entry>.*<title>(.*)</title>.*<published>(.*)</published>(.*)</entry>|xsU"
```

And now the capturing works. I get the title and the published date and the large chunk of final data that I don't want.

I tried to add the non capturing string "?:" to the last subgroup but then capturing stopped working alltogether again.

So how do I capture the data I want, without having to capture the large chunk of unwanted data at the end?

Comment: [Don't parse XML/HTML with regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) (or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML)) for parsing RSS/Atom feeds. You will get way better results than with regular expressions.

Here's an example (using SimpleXML):

```
$rss_feed = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/4187945');
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($rss_feed);

$title = $sxml->entry[0]->title;
echo $title;
```

Comment: The `(.*)` doesn't match everything (nor does it match `</title>`).  The [`U` Pattern Modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) was set, so it matches in UnGreedy mode...  Otherwise +1 for DOM/SimpleXML parsing...

Comment: @ircmaxell: You're right. I missed that `U` modifier bit. Thanks.

Comment: I definitely would use SimpleXml if I could but I want to stay vanilla and compatible with PHP4 (yes a bit stupid i know ^^). The only alternative I found then was xml_parser which I tried but that ended with a lot of clunky code. A simple regexp looks far more attractive to me with lesser impact from PHP/module requirements.

Comment: PHP4 has [DOM-XML](http://php.net/domxml). The `xml_parser` method might create more code, but at least it respects the XML parser standards. You would have a lot of work on your hands if you wanted to match the XML specification with a regular expression, because it's impossible... Also I think there's no good reason to even think about PHP4 ever again: it's no longer supported.

Comment: As far as I can tell DOM-XML is not enabled by default in PHP4? Basicly I want this to run on a default installation of PHP4/5, without any required extra libraries. Sure this is a sound answer, I have considered dropping support for PHP4 and then I would use SimpleXml. But I'm still intrigued by the original question: why does one regexp work while the other doesn't?

Comment: Either way, don't use a regex.  Otherwise it'll bork on the otherwise valid: `<title><![CDATA[<title>Something's wrong!</title>]]></title>` (which is actually done more than you would think for the description tags)

Comment: @ircmaxwell Use of patterns does not *ipso facto* require borkage: it all depends on [just how careful you are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044946/regex-to-split-html-tags/4045840#4045840).

Comment: @tchrist: That doesn't account for `CDATA` blocks.  Sure, in his code he does, but he only is able to achieve that by literally deleting any instance of that style tag.  So if for some reason the `<title>` tag had a `CDATA` data segment, it wouldn't work...  I'd bet that it's literally impossible to write a single regex that can successfully parse valid XML in all circumstances...  Then again, I'd love to be proven wrong here...

Comment: @ircmaxwell: What do you mean *he*? It’s my code. Show me what doesn't work.  The `CDATA` doesn't matter; put in a `<title>` tag and I’ll ignore it. I realize this is heresy, but of course you parse markup languages with rexegy bits (which are the user-friendly automaton interface): they're a critical component in virtually any parser. That doesn’t mean you just use a single pattern to do it! And don’t tell me recursion is a problem, either — [it’s not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031112/regular-expression-matching/4034386#4034386). That said, I certainly use parsing classes for such.

Comment: @tchrist: Sorry, I didn't quickly realize that was your code.  And nobody ever said you can't parse *parts* of XML with regex.  All we said is that you can't reliably parse the entirety in a single regex (the REGEX is just not expressive enough).  Sure, you can custom build a parser to do whatever you want, but there's no one generic regex you can write that will catch all valid edge cases (even in your `()` example)... And the point with XML is that why should you bother trying to build a monolithic parser to handle the parsing with regex, when you have full blown DOM parsers already written?

Comment: @tchrist: Regex is *not* a critical component in parsers. A lot of parsers I've worked with or into (e.g.: libxml's) use sequential reading to build the parse tree, not a *regular expression processor* (like PCRE). In fact, PCRE is a parser itself.

Comment: Ok, I extracted the code from the project now, and it turns out that it works fine. I'm still quite confused about why I get the error but now it seems like the regexp isn't the root problem and that I might have screwed up somewhere else entirely. For example the source data is passed through a database before it's passed to the regexp. Anyway that kind of makes the original question obsolete. I'll accept this answer since it contains sound advice :)