# Java regex help -- white space is killing me

Tags: java, regex

Alright, so I have the following output:

```
<p style="margin-top: 0">

</p>
```

that I want to be replaced with `<br />`. I have the following code:

```
string.replaceAll("<p([^>]*)></p>","<br/>");
```

What would I need to put between the > and < tags in order to replace only paragraph tags that have white space? That is, no characters or number between them.

Thanks

Comment: Is this ASCII data or UTF-8 data?

Comment: Obligatory reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: The summary of what David linked to: Don't use Regex on HTML/XML

Comment: @Andrew: Don’t use a nuclear warhead when a slingshot will do. Heresy it may be, but it is perfectly acceptable and indeed advisable to use regex for HTML and XML **provided** that they are well-defined subsets under your control. For example, if you’ve generated them yourself so that you know you don’t have arbitrarily complex craziness. For small problems that meet a certain sort of prediability, regexes are absolutely 100% fine. Of coure, somebody who doesn’t even know how to match Unicode whitespace (which is *hard* in Java, dang it!) should never attempt such a thing.

Comment: @tchrist: Maybe you meant to post your comment as a reply to David Gelhar, which is who posted the link. I was merely summarizing it. I didn't say I agree with it. (nor that I disagree with it, for that matter... my belief is closer to yours than the 'purists' on this one)

Comment: @David: This is for a very simple project that will never see anything even close to production. I know any and all input that would go in, and just needed to clear this bit up to clean up the output without going through too much trouble. So, although I wouldn't suggest anyone to do something like this in an application that wold be used in the real world, it fits my application perfectly. I do thank you for the concern, however.

Comment: @user485418: Given that restricted domain, regexes seem the right answer.  Just be careful with Java and Unicode: its charclass alias like `\w` and `\s` only work on ASCII.  It’s really lame.

Comment: See my comment to you below my answer. using \p{Zs} will handle Unicode whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.replaceAll("<p([^>]*)>\\s+?</p>","<br/>");
```

That should handle most scenarios. It is a non-greedy repetition where at least one whitespace character is required. Of course, using an HTML parser would yield more consistent results.

Comment: I cannot possibly see what a minimal vs a maximal ASCII whitespace match is going to buy you.  Also, my HTML pages are constantly full of `\x85` and `\xA0` characters.  Javs’s `\s` implementation is busted, you know.

Comment: “Safer”?  I think I’m going to go join the Cthulhu crowd. Sheesh!

Comment: Perhaps the original poster controls the HTML and just needs to perform a transformation on the files? I agree that regular expressions usually are the solution for XML parsing. But for simple text munging, I can't tell you how many times I've fired up vim and used search and replace to transform legacy data quickly.

Comment: Also, if the requirement is to match all Unicode whitespace characters, \\s+? can be replaced with \\p{Zs}+? wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Just noticed my above comment says "regular expressions usually are the solution for XML parsing". That "are" should have been "aren't"!

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
string.replaceAll("<p([^>]*)>\\s*</p>", "<br/>");
```

Comment: That’s a pretty naïve regex. You have to be [a whole lot more careful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044946/regex-to-split-html-tags/4045840#4045840) to stand any chance of doing it correctly.

Comment: @user485418: last I checked, Java’s `\s` was only good for ASCII data.  Hope that’s what you’ve got.