# How to find out particular value in a input field without regex using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the given html code name_with_initials such as mr,mrs,ms,master.While retrieving name from database it is like "MR:Raju" Based on this value i need to select value in of prefix name(MR) and name(Raju) should be in input box.How to do this?

```
<div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <select name="name_with_initials" id="name_with_initials">
                      <option value="MR">MR</option>
                      <option value="MRS">MRS</option>
                      <option value="MS">MS</option>
                      <option value="MASTER">MASTER</option>
                    </select>
                  </span>
                  <input type="text" name="name_with_initials" id="customername" onKeyPress="return ValidateAlpha(event);" class="form-control detailinfo" placeholder="Full Name">
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Comment: have u tried something so far?

Comment: So effectively, you are asking how you can split a string value at a particular character, in this case the colon? That is something you should be able to easily research on your own, for nearly _any_ programming language. Please make an effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to split HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044946/regex-to-split-html-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the initials and name with colon(:) and set the values to the select dropdown and input text box:

```js
var dbValue = 'MR:Raju';
var initials = dbValue.split(':')[0];
var username = dbValue.split(':')[1];
$('#name_with_initials').val(initials);
$('#customername').val(username);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <select name="name_with_initials" id="name_with_initials">
      <option value="MR">MR</option>
      <option value="MRS">MRS</option>
      <option value="MS">MS</option>
      <option value="MASTER">MASTER</option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="name_with_initials" id="customername" onKeyPress="return ValidateAlpha(event);" class="form-control detailinfo" placeholder="Full Name">
</div>
```

Comment: @Diamond glad to help :)