# Create list of string from one big string

Tags: c#, parsing, serialization, windows-8, app-store

I have one big string with many words and I need every word which start with string **stations:** add to list like item. Here is example> Its windows 8 store app

```
var myBigString = myStrings;
```

myBigString contains this: **stations: \"Budatínska\"\nstations: \"Bytčianska\"\n...**

How I can in cycle when is word **stations:** add new item **Budatínska** to my list of string.

Something like :

```
List<string> mylist= new List<string>();
foreach(mystring in bigString)
if(mystring=="stations") add.mylist...
```

Comment: Use a regex [Get started with regex (stackoverflow)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235445/get-started-with-regular-expression)

Comment: Sounds like a job for regex. Have you tried anything yourself? Or is this just another code request?

Comment: A simple `string.Split` seems to be enough.....

Comment: Yes I try regex but and I dont want full code. I only need idea how I can detect word in big string and then every time when is this word in big string add to list like new item. I am sorry if it sounded like I would like you to do all the work for me, merely seeking at least an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.Split`, like this:

```
string source = "stations: ONEstations: TWOstations: THREE";
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"stations:"};
string[] result;

result = source.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

foreach(string val in result)
{
    mylist.Add(val.Trim());
}
```

Note: `Trim()` will remove any leading and trailing white spaces.