# Validate email address from a text file?

Tags: perl

Im trying to search through a text file and find the valid email addresses.  Im doing something like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $infile = 'emails.txt';

    open IN, "< $infile" or die "Can't open $infile : $!";

    while( <IN> )
    { 
        if ($infile =~ /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/) 
        { 
            print "Valid \n"; 
        } 
    }

    close IN;
```

But it doesnt do anything, any help?

Comment: You should read RFC 5322 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322) because you are missing valid characters

Comment: How are the email addresses embedded in the file?  One complete address per line? Scattered among other data?  Can there be multiple addresses on one line? Can an email address be broken across multiple lines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You match the email address regexp against the name of the file. And anyway you should not use regex to validate email address - use Email::Valid

```
use strict;

use Email::Valid;

my $infile = 'emails.txt';

open my $in, "< $infile" or die "Can't open $infile : $!";

while(my $line = <$in> ) {

    chomp $line;

    if (Email::Valid->address($line)) {

        print "Valid \n";

    }


}

close $in;
```

Comment: To expand on why this is the right sort of answer, http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html is the sort of regex you need to actually validate email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match $infile, which contains the name of the text file, i.e. 'emails.txt'.

You should be doing something like

```
while(<IN>) {
     print "Valid \n" if $_ =~ /\bYOURREGEX\b/
}
```

This way \b matches word boundaries instead of the beginning and end of the line and you can match email addresses contained within another string.

EDIT: But Jira's answer is definitely better, this one just tells you what's wrong.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have problems with this regex unless:

1. The email address is the only thing in a line of the file
2. The email address in the file is all caps.

You should replace all `A-Z`, which only accepts caps, with `\p{Alpha}` all alpha characters regardless of case. Where you combine it with `0-9` and `_`. You should instead replace it with `\w` (any *word* character).

```
/^[\w.%+-]+@[\p{Alnum}.-]+\.\p{Alpha}{2,6}$/
```

This still isn't a valid regex for emails, though, see [Benoit's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268833/validate-email-address-from-a-text-file/4270139#comments-4268833)--but it might do the job in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Perl, but your Regular Expression is matching the beginning and end of the entire string. Unless you are setting a multi-line flag and/or only having 1 email address per file you won't get results.

Try removing the ^ (beginning of string) and $ (end of string) tokens and see if that helps any.

It might help to post a dataset sample as well. As without a sample I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need something like this?

```
@lines = <IN>;
close IN;

foreach $line (@lines)
{
...
}
```

Comment: This is slurping the file into an array.  Sometimes there's a good reason to slurp, but in most cases the best way to read the file is as jira has it.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a copy of [the regex to validate RFC 5322 email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764247/why-are-regular-expressions-so-controversial/4053506#4053506) here on SO, you know.  It looks like this:

```
$rfc5322 = qr{
    # etc
}x;
```

It has a thing or two in the `# etc` elision I’ve made above, which you can check out in the other answer.

By the way, if you’re going to use `\b` in your regexes, please please be especially careful that you know what it’s touching.

```
$boundary_before     =  qr{(?(?=\w)(?<!\w)|(?<=\w))}; # like /\bx/
$boundary_after      =  qr{(?(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?=\w))};  # like /x\b/
$nonboundary_before  =  qr{(?(?=\w)(?<=\w)|(?<!\w))}; # like /\Bx/
$nonboundary_after   =  qr{(?(?<=\w)(?=\w)|(?!\w))};  # like /x\B
```

That’s seldom what people are expecting.