# JavaScript regex to match links with uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex code that I want it to match any link preceded by `-`

this is my regex code

```
/-(\s+)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{1,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/
```

it already match these links

```
 - www.demo.com 
 - http://foo.co.uk/
```

But it doesn't match these

```
- WWW.TELEGRAM.COM
- WWW.c.COM
- t.mE/rrbot
```

you can  go to this link to check it http://regexr.com/3gnb1

Comment: put a /i at the end of your regex, this will make case-insensitive.

Comment: yes it works thank you

Comment: I've got to ask is there any reason you used `(\s+)?` instead of `\s*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two possible ways to go about it. Your regex currently excludes capital letters in the domain name, so you'd have to swap `.[a-z]{2,4}` for `.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` or then make the whole regex case insensitive. In the latter case, you can remove `A-Z` from the previous groups as well, resulting in:

```
/-(\s+)?[-a-z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{1,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you limiting the TLD to 4 characters? There are many valid TLDs that exceed beyond that such as `.finance`, `.movie`, `.academy`, etc.

You can use [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46105387/3600709) from a previous post and make some minor adjustments.

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<scheme>[a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*)
  (?<userpass>([^:@\/](:[^:@\/])?@))
  (?<domain>[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*)+)
  (?<ip>(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])))
  (?<host>((?&domain)|(?&ip)))
  (?<port>(:[\d]{1,5}))
  (?<path>([^?;\#\s]*))
  (?<query>(\?[^\#;\s]*))
  (?<anchor>(\#\S*))
)
(?:^)?-\ +((?:(?&scheme):\/\/)?(?&userpass)?(?&host)(?&port)?\/?(?&path)?(?&query)?(?&anchor)?)(?:$|\s+)
```

You can see this regex in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/4vW43B/2). This should catch all **valid** URLs (albeit the scheme is considered optional in your case, so I've made the scheme optional in the regex)