# Why does Java allow control characters in its identifiers?

Tags: java, variables, unicode

## The Mystery

In exploring precisely which characters were permitted in Java identifiers, I have stumbled upon something so extremely curious that it seems nearly certain to be a bug.

I’d expected to find that Java identifiers conformed to the requirement that they start with characters that have the Unicode property `ID_Start` and are followed by those with the property `ID_Continue`, with an exception granted for leading underscores and for dollar signs. That did not prove to be the case, and what I found is at extreme variance with that or any other idea of a normal identifier that I have heard of.

## Short Demo

Consider the following demonstration proving that an ASCII ESC character (octal 033) is permitted in Java identifiers:

```
$ perl -le 'print qq(public class escape { public static void main(String argv[]) { String var_\033 = "i am escape: \033"; System.out.println(var_\033); }})' > escape.java
$ javac escape.java
$ java escape | cat -v
i am escape: ^[
```

It’s even worse than that, though.  Almost infinitely worse, in fact.  Even NULLs are permitted! And thousands of other code points that are not even identifier characters. I have tested this on Solaris, Linux, and a Mac running Darwin, and all give the same results.

## Long Demo

Here is a test program that will show all these unexpected code points that Java quite outrageuosly allows as part of a legal identifier name.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# 
# test-java-idchars - find which bogus code points Java allows in its identifiers
# 
#   usage: test-java-idchars [low high]
#   e.g.:  test-java-idchars 0 255
#
# Without arguments, tests Unicode code points
# from 0 .. 0x1000.  You may go further with a
# higher explicit argument.
#
# Produces a report at the end.
#
# You can ^C it prematurely to end the program then
# and get a report of its progress up to that point.
#
# Tom Christiansen
# tchrist@perl.com
# Sat Jan 29 10:41:09 MST 2011

use strict;
use warnings;

use encoding "Latin1";
use open IO => ":utf8";

use charnames ();

$| = 1;

my @legal;

my ($start, $stop) = (0, 0x1000);

if (@ARGV != 0) {
    if (@ARGV == 1) {
        for (($stop) = @ARGV) { 
            $_ = oct if /^0/;   # support 0OCTAL, 0xHEX, 0bBINARY
        }
    }
    elsif (@ARGV == 2) {
        for (($start, $stop) = @ARGV) { 
            $_ = oct if /^0/;
        }
    } 
    else {
        die "usage: $0 [ [start] stop ]\n";
    } 
} 

for my $cp ( $start .. $stop ) {
    my $char = chr($cp);

    next if $char =~ /[\s\w]/;

    my $type = "?";
    for ($char) {
        $type = "Letter"      if /\pL/;
        $type = "Mark"        if /\pM/;
        $type = "Number"      if /\pN/;
        $type = "Punctuation" if /\pP/;
        $type = "Symbol"      if /\pS/;
        $type = "Separator"   if /\pZ/;
        $type = "Control"     if /\pC/;
    } 
    my $name = $cp ? (charnames::viacode($cp) || "<missing>") : "NULL";
    next if $name eq "<missing>" && $cp > 0xFF;
    my $msg = sprintf("U+%04X %s", $cp, $name);
    print "testing \\p{$type} $msg...";
    open(TESTPROGRAM, ">:utf8", "testchar.java") || die $!;

print TESTPROGRAM <<"End_of_Java_Program";

public class testchar { 
    public static void main(String argv[]) { 
        String var_$char = "variable name ends in $msg";
        System.out.println(var_$char); 
    }
}

End_of_Java_Program

    close(TESTPROGRAM) || die $!;

    system q{
        ( javac -encoding UTF-8 testchar.java \
            && \
          java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 testchar | grep variable \
        ) >/dev/null 2>&1
    };

    push @legal, sprintf("U+%04X", $cp) if $? == 0;

    if ($? && $? < 128) {
        print "<interrupted>\n";
        exit;  # from a ^C
    } 

    printf "is %s in Java identifiers.\n",  
        ($? == 0) ? uc "legal" : "forbidden";

} 

END { 
    print "Legal but evil code points: @legal\n";
}
```

Here is a sample of running that program on just the first 33 code points that are neither whitespace nor identifier characters:

```
$ perl test-java-idchars 0 0x20
testing \p{Control} U+0000 NULL...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0001 START OF HEADING...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0002 START OF TEXT...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0003 END OF TEXT...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0004 END OF TRANSMISSION...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0005 ENQUIRY...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0006 ACKNOWLEDGE...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0007 BELL...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0008 BACKSPACE...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+000B LINE TABULATION...is forbidden in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+000E SHIFT OUT...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+000F SHIFT IN...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0010 DATA LINK ESCAPE...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0011 DEVICE CONTROL ONE...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0012 DEVICE CONTROL TWO...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0013 DEVICE CONTROL THREE...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0014 DEVICE CONTROL FOUR...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0015 NEGATIVE ACKNOWLEDGE...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0016 SYNCHRONOUS IDLE...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0017 END OF TRANSMISSION BLOCK...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0018 CANCEL...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0019 END OF MEDIUM...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+001A SUBSTITUTE...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+001B ESCAPE...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+001C INFORMATION SEPARATOR FOUR...is forbidden in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+001D INFORMATION SEPARATOR THREE...is forbidden in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+001E INFORMATION SEPARATOR TWO...is forbidden in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+001F INFORMATION SEPARATOR ONE...is forbidden in Java identifiers.
Legal but evil code points: U+0000 U+0001 U+0002 U+0003 U+0004 U+0005 U+0006 U+0007 U+0008 U+000E U+000F U+0010 U+0011 U+0012 U+0013 U+0014 U+0015 U+0016 U+0017 U+0018 U+0019 U+001A U+001B
```

And here is another demo:

```
$ perl test-java-idchars 0x600 0x700 | grep -i legal
testing \p{Control} U+0600 ARABIC NUMBER SIGN...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0601 ARABIC SIGN SANAH...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0602 ARABIC FOOTNOTE MARKER...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+0603 ARABIC SIGN SAFHA...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
testing \p{Control} U+06DD ARABIC END OF AYAH...is LEGAL in Java identifiers.
Legal but evil code points: U+0600 U+0601 U+0602 U+0603 U+06DD
```

## The Question

Can anyone please explain this seemingly insane behavior?  There are many, many, many other inexplicably permitted code points all over the place, starting right off with U+0000, which is perhaps the strangest of all.  If you run it on the first 0x1000 code points, you do see certain patterns appear, such as permitting any and all code points with the property `Current_Symbol`.  But too much else is wholly inexplicable, at least by me.

Comment: What version of the Java language are you using?  IIRC early versions had the rule that "If the character does not belong to one of a few specific classes, it's treated as alphanumeric and allowed in identifiers" but I thought that was dropped in later versions.

Comment: This really sucks, and it's a really good question. I also don't get why they allow national characters in identifiers. Imagine what a source would look like if it used Chinese identifiers. Or Japanese. Or even Hebrew, written right-to-left. The same goes for C#, really. One of my colleagues actually uses Russian identifiers. It looks terrible, often even for a native Russian (myself included).

Comment: @finnw: This is version 1.6 of Java.

Comment: @Sergey: It would make perfect sense if Java followed the Unicode standard and allowed identifiers of the form `^\p{ID_Start}\p{ID_Continue}*$`. But that is not what they are doing.

Comment: @tchrist, it would make perfect sense if Java only allowed identifiers of the form `^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*$` as any sensible old school language does. I see absolutely no reason to use anything else in identifiers. It only makes code less readable. This is even worse than IDNs which are at least targeted towards regular users, not programmers.

Comment: I sometimes use Greek letters as identifiers, if they were used in the mathematical formula my method is based on.  I find it more readable than replacing them with English spellings like "omega", if I am looking at the code in one window and the equation in another.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615/should-you-use-international-identifiers-in-java-c

Comment: @finnw: No, this is not really related.  I am talking about why Java allows the C0 and C1 control sets (amongst others) in identifiers. There is no question that allowing any valid Unicode alphabetic or numeric is the right thing. It’s the invisible stuff that bugs me.

Comment: Is the test code valid? If a control character is interpreted as whitespace, the code will report the character as legal (because `var_` is a legal identifier). A solution could be to put the character in the middle of the identifier.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification section 3.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8) defers to [Character.isJavaIdentifierStart()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart%28char%29) and [Character.isJavaIdentifierPart()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart%28char%29). The latter, among other conditions, has [Character.isIdentifierIgnorable()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isIdentifierIgnorable%28char%29), which allows non-whitespace control characters (including whole C1 range, see the link for the list).

Comment: So Java has one again decided to fabricate their own definitions of things in a fashion that is out of step with the Unicode standard?  I’d really like to know why — **at most** — the Unicode `Default_Ignorable_Code_Point` property proved insufficient for their mysterious purposes, and why they had to go inventing their own definitions that contradict Unicode. It makes as much sense as Java having its own notion of white space that differs from Unicode’s — which it indeed has.

Comment: That does not explain many of the inexplicably permitted code points, like U+0602 ARABIC FOOTNOTE MARKER and U+070F SYRIAC ABBREVIATION MARK and U+2062 INVISIBLE TIMES are all Gc=Cf aka General_Category=Format.  Those are not type `\w` characters at all! What’s with **invisible**, anyways? What are they smoking? You can’t tell which is signficant and which is ignorable: unequal strings should not test equal. Might as well use identifiers that are not just case-insensitive but where all vowels test equal. Makes as much (non)sense!

Comment: @tchrist: I know I haven't answered the "why", but seriously, only the creators of Java can give you a definitive answer on that, so you should probably try to reach them, it should be easier for you than for the rest of us.

Answer (score 8):

Another question might be: Why shouldn't Java allow control characters in its identifiers?

A good principle when designing a language or other system, is to not forbid anything without good cause, since you never know how it might be used, and the less rules implementers and users have to contend with, the better.

It is true that you certainly shouldn't take advantage of this, by actually embedding escapes into your variable names, and you won't see any popular libraries that expose classes with null characters in them.

Certainly, this could be abused, but it isn't the language designers job to protect programmers from themselves in this way, any more than by forcing proper indentation or well-chosen variable names.

Comment: @Avi: There are many reasons why Java should not allow control characters in its identifiers!! To start with, control characters are *not* ID_Start characters, they are *not* ID_Continue characters, **and** they are *not* Default_Ignorable_Code_Point characters. For another, they are invisible. And for a third, this is just plain sloppy.  It’s bad design! You have two unequal identifiers treated as though they were identical even though they are not. What a mess!

Comment: First of all, IS_Start and ID_Continue, AFAIK, were defined in UAX #31, an annex to Unicode 5.0, well after the Java language syntax was defined. Any change to legal characters in Java at that point would have been an unnecessary, non-backward-compatible, change.

Comment: Second of all, I'm not sure how you can have two unequal identifiers treated as equal. What you can have is two identifiers that *look* identical, treated differently. But that is true even if you just allow letters and numbers and mathematical symbols: for example, Greek letter mu (U+03BC) looks the same as the mathematical symbol micron (U+00B5).

Comment: @Avi: The knee-jerk invocation of Backwards Contemptible does little to promote recognizing that standards exist. There are ways to be compliant with new standards while still compiling old code in the backwards way. To ignore the future is to die.

Comment: @tchrist: Agreed, which is why I wrote "*unnecessary*, non-backward-compatible". If it were a big deal, it would be worth breaking backward compatibility or making tighter rules for new code, such as was done for the `assert` and `enum` keywords when they were introduced. But it really isn't - who ever would think of putting control characters in source identifiers anyway, and if they do, who cares?

Comment: @Avi: the fact that BS (not to even begin talking of CSI) is legal in Java could potentially make code audits all that more interesting.

Comment: True, though if you are programming in an environment where you are doing code audits for security reasons, you probably should be using something like FindBugs or PMD. You can easily add rules to these to check for control characters.

Comment: @avi new versions of Java bring new restrictions.  This could easily have been tightened in Java 7.  A bit of lobbying might bring it in java 8

Answer (score -3):

I don't see what's the big deal. How does it affect you in anyway?

If a developer wants to obfuscate his code, he can do it with ASCII.

If a developer wants to make his code understandable, he will use the lingua franca of the industry: English. Not only identifiers are ASCII only, but also from common English words. Otherwise, nobody will use or read his code, he can use whatever crazy characters he likes.

Comment: This idea that English and ASCII were good enough for Grandpa in Iowa so it better be good enough for Rajesh in New Delhi, let alone for Akira in Kyoto, is deeply troubling. It is imperialistic and condescending. It runs right over other people’s sensitivies. Might as well renege on Java using Unicode for its default character set and lobby for a return to the 1960s when ASCII was considered an improvement.

Comment: The more I look at Unicode, the more I get the feeling that ASCII could be an improvement. Letting people use their national characters may be good idea provided they never cooperate with foreigners. For most people there's no way how to write Greek letters or even most accented Latin letters. Most foreign characters can't be read by most people. So what is it all good for in a programming language?

Comment: The Rajesh in New Delhi is very offended by you. What's the point of a language other than communicating? Why do millions programmers all speak Java? why not everybody invents a new language?

Comment: @irreputable - it's not a question of being practically affected, but of a standard hacker type curiosity questioning the "whys" and the "hows" of things. Matter of fact the question arouse of tchrist's extended answer to a question asking for a grammar defining Perl's valid identifiers - he mentioned the Java conundrum and people badgered him to ask the "why" as a separate question instead.

Comment: @irreputable: this is not an answer to the question. To question the question, use comments on the question.

Comment: @dolmen You're right but all the others answers are no real answers either. To find one, we'd need to know what the Java designers smoked that time.