# Perl qq and underscore

Tags: string, perl, quotes

So I have two variables

```
$x = q(foo);
$y = q(bar);
```

My goal is to use them in a third variable with an underscore between them i.e. `foo_bar`. There are lots of ways to do this, but I wanted to use `qq`

so

```
$z = qq($x_$y);
```

This gives the following error

```
Global symbol "$x_" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 45.
Execution of C:\test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

So I had to use curly brackets with the variable `x` to make it work

```
$z = qq(${x}_$y);
```

Why does underscore not work with `qq`? Why do I need curly brackets in this case?

Comment: `qq($x_$y)` is exactly the same as `$x_ . $y`. You need curlies because that's not what you want.

Comment: Re: `Why does underscore not work with qq?` It's not just `qq()`, the same issue you'll have with `"$x_$y";` for reason explained in answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `_` counts as a letter in identifiers (such as variable names).

When you write `"$x_$y"`, Perl thinks you're trying to interpolate two variables, `$x_` and `$y`. Similarly, when you write `"$foo$bar"`, Perl thinks you're trying to interpolate `$foo` and `$bar` (not `$f . 'oo' . $bar` or `$fo . 'o' . $bar` or any other combination).

The general rule is: Names extend as far to the right as possible (that is, Perl chooses the longest possible interpretation for identifiers).

Answer (score 4):

The underscore `_` is a legitimate character to use in variable names, so when you say `"$x_$y"` you are referring to (evaluating) a variable `$x_`, which clearly has not been defined.

See, for example, the accepted answer in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800275/what-characters-are-allowed-in-perl-identifiers) for this and a lot more of this kind.

Comment: Seriously, you are among the best of us here, and I will be pleased when your "score" matches your ability

Comment: @Borodin Oh, uh, that is way too kind of you to say, thank you.  (Now _that_ is embarrassing.)  Now I need to work really, really hard for it! So that perhaps some years down the line it's somewhat true :).  Thank you for helping all along the way.  I'll tidy up now, all of this is personal, so OT

Answer (score 3):

Because underscore may be part of the identifier. Otherwise, how parser should distinct $x from $x_ ?

So braces says that only x is identifer, not x_

Answer (score 2):

If you want it your way, then you should just escape the underscore character.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x =qq(foo);
my $y=qq(bar);
my $z = qq($x\_$y);

print $z;
```

Ofcourse I would like to suggest that this is not the better way. The curly brace way is the most better approach.

Answer (score 1):

According to perl variable naming rull 'underscore' can be a part of the variable name. ref : http://sivasakthikumar.blogspot.in/2009/03/variable-names-can-start-with-letter_16.html

That's why its not able understand your variable name properly.So you need brackets.