# PCRE regular expressions using named pattern subroutines

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am experimenting with the named subpattern/'subroutine' regex features in PHP's PCRE and I'm hoping someone can explain the following strange output:

```
$re = "/
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<a> a )
)

^(?&a)$

/x";

var_dump(preg_match($re, 'a', $match)); // (int) 1 as expected
var_dump($match); // Array( [0] => 'a' ) <-- Why?
```

I can't understand why the named group "a" is not in the result (with the contents "a").  Changing `preg_match` to `preg_match_all` puts "a" and "1" in the match data but both contain only an empty string.

I really like the idea of writing regular expressions this way, as you can make them incredibly powerful whilst keeping them very maintainable (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764247/why-are-regular-expressions-so-controversial/4053506#4053506) for a good example of this), however if the subpatterns are not available in the match data then it's not much use really.

Am I missing something here or should I just mourn what could have been and move on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes perfect sense these subpatterns would not capture a group - their main purpose it to be used more than once, so you can't really capture them all. In addition, if the default was to capture all subpatterns it wouldn't give you an option *not* to capture a group where you don't want it - not the best default behavior. The opposite is trivial - you can capture by adding another group around the `(?&a)` statement.
I couldn't find a reference to this on [PCRE.org](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt). The closest is this, which is relevant because you don't match `(?<a>...)` directly (though you might expect an empty group):

> Any capturing parentheses that
>          are set during the subroutine call  revert  to  their  previous  values
>          afterwards.

It is clearer on the [Perl manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (relevant part highlighted):

> An example of how this might be used is as follows:
>
> ```
> /(?<NAME>(?&NAME_PAT))(?<ADDR>(?&ADDRESS_PAT))
> (?(DEFINE)
> (?<NAME_PAT>....)
> (?<ADRESS_PAT>....)
> )/x
> ```
>
> Note that **capture buffers matched inside of recursion are not accessible after the recursion returns**, so the extra layer of capturing buffers is necessary.

Comment: Yes, that's right; this is how `(?(DEFINE)…)` works.  It’d like declaring subroutines. I sometimes use all-caps for named capture groups outside the define and lowercase for callable non-capturing groups within it, to help keep the two straight in my head. Look at the longer of the solution given [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284176/doubt-in-parsing-data-in-perl-where-am-i-going-wrong/4286326#4286326) for how I use named groups in both ways: for calling, and for capturing. The captured ones I pull out of the `%+` hash, like `$+{VALUE}` or `@⁠+⁠{ qw< TAG BODY > }`.