# Can you retrieve multiple regex matches in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression in JavaScript which matches strings like "12:23:34:45" and "12:23"

```
/^([0-9]{1,2}\:){0,3}([0-9]{0,2})?$/
```

The problem I have is that when I look at the match data there are only ever 3 matches returned. e.g. for 12:23:34:45 the matches returned are:

```
12:23:34:45
34:
45
```

i.e. the first capturing group only reports its last value. I would like the matches to be:

```
12:23:34:45
12:
23:
34:
45
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not possible in JavaScript (and most other regex flavors except Perl 6 and .NET). Repeated capturing groups always store the last value that was matched. Only .NET and Perl allow you to access those matches individually (`match.Groups(i).Captures` in .NET, for example).

You need two passes, the first to find the strings, the second to iterate over the matches and scan those for their sub-values.

Or make the regex explicit:

```
/^([0-9]{1,2}:)?([0-9]{1,2}:)?([0-9]{1,2}:)?([0-9]{0,2})?$/
```