# Get repeated matches with preg_match_all()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get all substrings matched with a multiplier:

```
$list = '1,2,3,4';
preg_match_all('|\d+(,\d+)*|', $list, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This example returns, as expected, the last match in `[1]`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1,2,3,4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ,4
        )

)
```

However, I would like to get all strings matched by `(,\d+)`, to get something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ,2
    [1] => ,3
    [2] => ,4
)
```

Is there a way to do this with a single function such as `preg_match_all()`?

Comment: Different language, but same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571106 : you can't, but you can easily split by `,`.

Comment: @Kobi: thank you for the link. From what they say, there are solutions in some languages, any hope for PHP or is it a definitive answer?

Comment: `[0] => ,2` is not possible with PHP. is `,2` a string or is it a number?

Comment: No. As far as I know, PHP has no support for captures of the same group, if you do insist on a whole-regex solution.

Comment: As already suggested: `explode(...)` is the better option here. You _could_ do: `preg_match_all('|(\d+)|', $list, $matches);`, but there is no guarantee the input string is a comma delimited string with numbers!

Comment: Thank you Kobi. If you had an answer, I would accept it :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Kobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7586/kobi) (see comments above):

> PHP has no support for captures of the same group

Therefore this question has no solution.

Answer (score 7):

It's true that PHP (or better to say PCRE) doesn't store values of repeated capturing groups for later access (see [PCRE docs](https://pcre.org/pcre.txt)):

> If a capturing subpattern is matched repeatedly, it is the last portion of the string that it matched that is returned.

But in most cases the known token `\G` does the job. `\G` 1) matches the beginning of input string (as `\A` or `^` when `m` modifier is not set) or 2) starts match from where the previous match ends. Saying that, you have to use it like the following:

```
preg_match_all('/^\d+|\G(?!^)(,?\d+)\K/', $list, $matches);
```

See [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/26spM)

or if capturing group doesn't matter:

```
preg_match_all('/\G,?\d+/', $list, $matches);
```

by which `$matches` will hold this (see [live demo](https://3v4l.org/Jig6i)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => ,2
            [2] => ,3
            [3] => ,4
        )

)
```

**Note**: the benefit of using `\G` over the other answers (like `explode()` or lookbehind solution or just `preg_match_all('/,?\d+/', ...)`) is that you are able to validate the input string to be only in the desired format `^\d+(,\d+)*$` at the same time while exporting the matches:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^(?=\d+(?:,\d+)*$)|\G(?!^),)\d+/', $list, $matches);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is a way to do the job:

```
$list = '1,2,3,4';
preg_match_all('|(?<=\d),\d+|', $list, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

All the `,\d+` are in group 0.

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ,2
            [1] => ,3
            [2] => ,4
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting is only an option when the character to split isn't used in the patterns to match itself.
I had a situation where a badly formatted comma separated line has to be parsed into any of a number of known options.

i.e. options '1,2', '2', '2,3'
subject '1,2,3'.

Splitting on ',' will result in '1', '2', and '3'; only one ('2') of which is a valid match, this happens because the separator is also part of the options.

The naïve regex would be something like '~^(1,2|2|2,3)(?:,(1,2|2|2,3))*$~i', but this runs into the problem of same-group captures.

My "solution" was to just expand the regex to match the maximum number of matches possible:
'~^(1,2|2|2,3)(?:,(1,2|2|2,3))?(?:,(1,2|2|2,3))?$~i'
(if more options were available, just repeat the '(?:,(1,2|2|2,3))?' bit.
This does result in empty string results for "unused" matches.

It's not the cleanest solution, but works when you have to deal with badly formatted input data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
$ar = explode(',', $list);
print_r($ar);
```

Comment: The example above is a simplification, the regexp is actually more complicated than that. I know how to do it the verbose way, I'm just curious to know whether there is a shorter path to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php :

> When a capturing subpattern is repeated, the value captured is the substring that matched the final iteration.

Also similar thread:

[How to get all captures of subgroup matches with preg_match_all()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371226/how-to-get-all-captures-of-subgroup-matches-with-preg-match-all/24269846)

Comment: These "hints" could have been a comment under the question.