# How to get the history of the captures

Tags: php, regex

*This is not only PHP problem as far as I can tell, but I am asking here about PHP (PHP7 actually).*

Consider such simple regex (if this is unclear -- it is an **example**):

```
/((\w+): (\d+))+/
```

and text for it:

```
foo: 2008bar: 2009
```

The match is over entire text, the problem is the sub-captures are used and forgotten as soon as the regex engine advances over the text. As the result you will get only the last captures.

I would like to get all valid (correct) captures, so entire history, no only the last captures.

Here is the code to test it:

```
<?php

$str = 'foo: 2008bar: 2009';

preg_match_all('/((\w+): (\d+))+/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

And here is the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo: 2008bar: 2009
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar: 2009
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2009
        )

)
```

As you can see entire text was matched, but for the captures only the last ones were stored. Those are missing:

```
foo: 2008
foo
2008
```

Thus my question: how to get entire "history" of the captures?

Comment: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pE7pE9/1) gives the same result...

Comment: This is expected behavior for PCRE. It does not support *repeated groups*. .NET/PyPi regex Python module and Boost (compiled with specific settings) support them.

Comment: is it working like this /((\w+):\s(\d+))/g

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, so my **only** choice in PHP is to bind to some of those engines? Could you please post this as a regular answer?

Comment: Just remove the last + and use the global flag `/((\w+): (\d+))/g`. There is no global flag with PHP but `preg_match_all` does the job. (Tested on regex101)

Comment: Use multiple matching (see John's suggestion and [this demo](https://ideone.com/xV5ZRS)).

Comment: @John, you do realize I showed an **example** right?

Comment: @greenoldman: Since the general solution is not possible, each case requires specific approach. What is your input like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get repeated matches with preg\_match\_all()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579908/get-repeated-matches-with-preg-match-all)

Answer (score 0):

When implementing a capture group with a quantifier (such as `*`, `+`, or `?`), the latest occurring match will overwrite all previous matches in the group.

It doesn't appear from your context to be necessary to match consecutive matches.  If you DO need to match consecutively occurring substrings, then `\G` (continue escape sequence) will be helpful. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/knB8n)

```
~\G(\w+): (\d+)~
```

To match all substrings, regardless of if they are consecutive, just allow `preg_match_all()` to return multiple matches (as it does normally) without using the quantifier `+`.  Because the outer capture group represents the fullstring match, you can omit this and eliminate the bloat of the returned array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fNjZd))

```
preg_match_all('~(\w+): (\d+)~', $str, $matches);
```