# Get regex to match multiple instances of the same pattern

Tags: regex

So I have this regex - [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/I0g6qW/3):

```
\[shortcode ([^ ]*)(?:[ ]?([^ ]*)="([^"]*)")*\]
```

Trying to match on this string

```
[shortcode contact param1="test 2" param2="test1"]
```

Right now, the regex matches this:

```
[contact, param2, test1]
```

I would like it to match this:

```
[contact, param1, test 2, param2, test1]
```

How can I get regex to match the first instance of the parameters pattern, rather than just the last?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579908/get-repeated-matches-with-preg-match-all/24269775

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So, if I were to use PHP for this, what I want is impossible?

Comment: Possible, with two regexps like [this](https://regex101.com/r/I0g6qW/4) and then [this one](https://regex101.com/r/I0g6qW/5). Or use something like `(?:\G(?!^)\s+|\[shortcode\s+(\S+)\s+)(\S+)="([^"]*)"` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/I0g6qW/6))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked a charm, thank you! If you post that as an answer I can confirm it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Using the other regex you provided, then parsing the result further with some PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?:\G(?!^)\s+|\[shortcode\s+(\S+)\s+)([^\s=]+)="([^"]*)"~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I0g6qW/7)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s+|\[shortcode\s+(\S+)\s+)` - either the end of the previous match and 1+ whitespaces right after (`\G(?!^)\s+`) or (`|`)

  - `\[shortcode` - literal string
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([^\s=]+)` - Group 2: 1+ chars other than whitespace and `=`
- `="` - a literal substring
- `([^"]*)` - Group 3: any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` -  a `"` char.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/NyMy1z)

```
$re = '~(?:\G(?!^)\s+|\[shortcode\s+(\S+)\s+)([^\s=]+)="([^"]*)"~';
$str = '[shortcode contact param1="test 2" param2="test1"]';
$res = [];
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        array_shift($m);
        $res = array_merge($res, array_filter($m));
    }
}
print_r($res);
// => Array( [0] => contact [1] => param1  [2] => test 2 [3] => param2  [4] => test1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below regex.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QLuPI7/1)

Below is your use case,

var testString = '[shortcode contact param1="test 2" param2="test1"]';

var regex = /[\w\s]+(?=[\="]|\")/gm;

var found = paragraph.match(regex);

If you log **found** you will see the result as

["shortcode contact param1", "test 2", " param2", "test1"]

The regex will match all the alphanumeric character including the underscore and blank spaces only if they are followed by **="** or **"**.

I hope this helps.