# Regex - Match separated numbers

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Matching the regex `/^(?:\.(\d{3}))*$/s` on `.234.567` produces the following output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '.234.567' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '567' (length=3)
```

Why is `234` not listed in the second subarray?

Answer (score 0):

> As @develroot already has answered the way you want to use preg_match_all does not work, it will only return the last matching group, not all captures of that group. That's how regex works.

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/6635830/1515333)