# How to find leaf arrays in nested arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I have a nested array in PHP:

```
array (
'0' => "+5x",
'1' => array (
       '0' => "+",
       '1' => "(",
       '2' => "+3",
       '3' => array (
              '0' => "+",
              '1' => "(",
              '2' => array ( // I want to find this one.
                  '0' => "+",
                  '1' => "(",
                  '2' => "+5",
                  '3' => "-3",
                  '4' => ")"
                  ),
              '3' => "-3",
              '4' => ")"
              ),
       '4' => ")"
       )
);
```

I need to process the innermost arrays, ones that themselves contain no arrays. In the example, it's the one with the comment: "I want to find this one." Is there a function for that?

I have thought about doing (written as an idea, not as correct PHP):

```
foreach ($array as $id => $value) {
    if ($value is array) {
        $name = $id;
        foreach ($array[$id] as $id_2 => $value_2) {
            if ($value_2 is array) {
                $name .= "." . $id_2;
                foreach ($array[$id][$id_2] as $id_3 => $value_3) {
                    if ($value_3 is array) {
                        $name .= "." . $id_3;
                        foreach ($array[$id][$id_2][$id_3] as $id_4 => $value_4) {
                            if ($value_4 is array) {
                                $name .= "." . $id_4;
                                foreach [and so it goes on];
                            } else {
                                $listOfInnerArrays[] = $name;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $listOfInnerArrays[] = $name;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $listOfInnerArrays[] = $name;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what it does is it makes `$name` the current key in the array. If the value is an array, it goes into it with foreach and adds "." and the id of the array. So we would in the example array end up with:

```
array (
    '0' => "1.3.2",
)
```

Then I can process those values to access the inner arrays.

The problem is that the array that I'm trying to find the inner arrays of is dynamic and made of a user input. (It splits an input string where it finds + or -, and puts it in a separate nested array if it contains brackets. So if the user types a lot of brackets, there will be a lot of nested arrays.)
Therefore I need to make this pattern go for 20 times down, and still it will only catch 20 nested arrays no matter what.

Is there a function for that, again? Or is there a way to make it do this without my long code? Maybe make a loop make the necessary number of the foreach pattern and run it through `eval()`?

Comment: There are several recursive functions build using `array_search()` that might help you retrieve what you need.  Just search through the user comments here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php.  Would these do what you want?

Comment: What exactly sets apart `"Content"` from `"I want to find this one."`? Short of matching strings, I'm not sure how you can differentiate between these strings.

Comment: I didn't find anything there, unfortunately.

Comment: That's the thing that makes this difficult. I can't search for anything, because I have no idea what's inside the deepest one.

What happens is this:

The user inputs an equation. The script splits each term into each own line in the array. If there is a bracket in one of the terms, or the lines in the newly created array, it'll make a new array inside the array and split it up. It could note the name when it does this, but as the script grows complex it will at some point be some functions that can't do this.

I need to do this so that the script can get the inner bracket and work with it.

Comment: @50ndr33 Then this seems to be impossible. Do you have some real data that you can show in place of the filler in your first code block? If the parts you're looking for have a pattern, you might be able to match them with a regex.

Comment: If it is 5x+3=(x+(3+(5-3))), then I need to get to the inner array which contains (5-3) so that the script can turn it into 2 instead of an array. If I have to explain more, or set it up as an array, tell me :)

Comment: I'm making an array right now to show you.

Comment: @50ndr33: why would the program then not go on to simplify "3+2"? Do the expressions follow the standard order of operations?

Comment: ... Questions, like [sample code](http://sscce.org/) and answers, should be self contained rather than linking to other sites for essential information (non-essential, additional information can simply be linked to).

Comment: You are just trying to find the ARRAY inside of the ARRAY.  use is_array() and then you're golden... right??

Comment: The parsed format looks unwieldy to work with. Look up "expression trees" for a better approach.

Comment: Oh, since an equation contains x and maybe y it can't be run directly as $result = $_POST[...] I have to process it manually. So I first have to remove the inner brackets. If there is plus or minus in it, then I just have to plus them together.

Comment: @outis I know, but when I wrote it I used <pre>, and it told me I was doing the code part wrong, so I did that instead of writing everything over again.

Comment: @Shackrock If I was going to find an array inside an array, it would have been easy. But I'm going to find an array inside an array inside an array inside an array and so on. The problem is that I don't know how far it'll go and it could go like this 40 times.

Comment: @50ndr33: the nesting isn't hard to deal with; write a recursive function. What makes this more difficult is the format of the parsed expression.

Comment: @outis: Do you mean like he did in the answer here? I tried that, but it didn't work. I added some comments on the results in the question.

Comment: @50ndr33 use foreach to cycle through, just as you did..but do it recursively.  I'm adding an answer below.

Comment: @50ndr33: this questions seems to suffer from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What you want to do is simplify an expression, not simply find arrays with no sub-arrays, correct? And who do you mean by "he?" J. Bruni? Not quite. In this case, you should write a custom recursive function rather than using a built-in one to traverse the array.

Comment: @outis Well, I have made a script that splits each term into its own line in the array. Since everything inside a bracket is one term even though it consists of several terms. Therefore I want a array inside the array to divide the terms of the brackets. But if that bracket contains a bracket again and so on it will be a lot of arrays inside the array. I thought that this method was the best, because then I always have full control over each part of the equation.

Comment: @outis Then the script can do $equationLeft[$id] to "select" the term and work with it. For example it can fix the term 3x*5 into 15*x. It can go through with foreach() if preg_match +(number)+[^xy*] then plus/minus the terms together.

Comment: @outis I already wrote some functions working in this manner, but if you know a better way of doing it, then I would REALLY appreciate your opinion! :)

Comment: @50ndr33: that doesn't address my questions. What's the [overall goal](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)? Expression simplification? If so, that should be edited into the question. SO uses a Q&A rather than forum format; posts aren't supposed to be discussions, and each question and answer shouldn't require reading the comments to understand. For discussions, use the SO chat rooms. As for input from me, see my answer.

Comment: ... Is this an assignment, for self-education or for production code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5167/discussion-between-outis-and-50ndr33)

Comment: @50ndr33 Please, edit your question and remove your answer to me from it. And, please, test the new code I have just made for you (see my edited answer). It works! Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Definitions

**simple:**

Describes expressions without sub-expressions (e.g. "5", "x").

**compound:**

Describes expressions that have sub-expressions (e.g. "3+x", "1+2").

**constness:**

Whether an expression has a constant value (e.g. "5", "1+2") or not (e.g. "x", "3+x").

**outer node:**

In an expression tree, a node reachable by always traversing left or always traversing right. "Outer" is always relative to a given node; a node might be "outer" relative to one node, but "inner" relative to that node's parent.

**inner node:**

In an expression tree, a node that isn't an outer node.

For an illustration of "inner" and "outer" nodes, consider:

```
       __1__
      /     \ 
     2       5
    / \     / \
   3   4   6   7
```

3 and 7 are always outer nodes. 6 is outer relative to 5, but inner relative to 1.

## Answer

The difficulty here lies more in the uneven expression format than the nesting. If you use expression trees, the example `5x+3=(x+(3+(5-3)))` equation would parse to:

```
array(
    '=' => array(
        '+' => array( // 5x + 3
            '*' => array(
                5, 'x'
            ),
            3
        )
        '+' => array( // (x+(3+(5-3)))
            'x',
            '+' => array( // (3+(5-3))
                3,
                '-' => array(
                    5, 3
)   )   )   )   )
```

Note that nodes for binary operations are binary, and unary operations would have unary nodes. If the nodes for binary commutative operations could be combined into n-ary nodes, `5x+3=x+3+5-3` could be parsed to:

```
array(
    '=' => array(
        '+' => array( // 5x + 3
            '*' => array(
                5, 'x'
            ),
            3
        )
        '+' => array( // x+3+5-3
            'x',
            3,
            '-' => array(
                5, 3
)   )   )   )
```

Then, you'd write a post-order recursive function that would simplify nodes. "Post-order" means node processing happens after processing its children; there's also pre-order (process a node before its children) and in-order (process some children before a node, and the rest after). What follows is a rough outline. In it, "thing : Type" means "thing" has type "Type", and "&" indicates pass-by-reference.

```
simplify_expr(expression : Expression&, operation : Token) : Expression {
    if (is_array(expression)) {
        foreach expression as key => child {
            Replace child with simplify_expr(child, key); 
                key will also need to be replaced if new child is a constant 
                and old was not.
        }
        return simplify_node(expression, operation);
    } else {
        return expression;
    }
}

simplify_node(expression : Expression&, operation : Token) : Expression;
```

In a way, the real challenge is writing `simplify_node`. It could perform a number of operations on expression nodes:

1. If an inner grand-child doesn't match the constness of the other child but its sibling does, swap the siblings. In other words, make the odd-man-out an outer node. This step is in preparation for the next.

   ```
       +            +                +            +
      / \          / \              / \          / \
     \+   2  --->  +   2            +   y  --->  +   y
    / \          / \              / \          / \
   1   x        x   1            x   1        1   x
   ```
2. If a node and a child are the same commutative operation, the nodes could be rearranged. For example, there's rotation:

   ```
       +            +
      / \          / \
     \+   c  --->  a   +
    / \              / \
   a   b            b   c
   ```

   This corresponds to changing "(a+b)+c" to "a+(b+c)". You'll want to rotate when "a" doesn't match the constness of "b" and "c". It allows the next transformation to be applied to the tree. For example, this step would convert "(x+3)+1" to "x+(3+1)", so the next step could then convert it to "x+4".

   The overall goal is to make a tree with const children as siblings. If a commutative node has two const descendants, they can be rotated next to each other. If a node has only one const descendent, make it a child so that a node further up in the hierarchy can potentially combine the const node with another of the ancestor's const children (i.e. const nodes float up until they're siblings, at which point they combine like bubbles in soda).
3. If all children are constant, evaluate the node and replace it with the result.

Handling nodes with more than one compound child and n-ary nodes left as exercises for the reader.

### Object-Oriented Alternative

An OO approach (using objects rather than arrays to build expression trees) would have a number of advantages. Operations would be more closely associated with nodes, for one; they'd be a property of a node object, rather than as the node key. It would also be easier to associate ancillary data with expression nodes, which would be useful for optimizations. You probably wouldn't need to get too deep into the OOP paradigm to implement this. The following simple type hierarchy could be made to work:

```
                   Expression
                  /          \
        SimpleExpr            CompoundExpr
        /        \
ConstantExpr    VariableExpr
```

Existing free functions that manipulate trees would become methods. The interfaces could look something like the following pseudocode. In it:

- `Child < Parent` means "Child" is a subclass of "Parent".
- Properties (such as `isConstant`) can be methods or fields; in PHP, you can implement this using [overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).
- `(...){...}` indicate functions, with the parameters between parentheses and the body between brackets (much like `function (...){...}` in Javascript). This syntax is used for properties that are methods. Plain methods simply use brackets for the method body.

Now for the sample:

```
Expression {
    isConstant:Boolean
    simplify():Expression
}

SimpleExpr < Expression {
    value:Varies
    /* simplify() returns an expression so that an expression of one type can 
       be replaced with an expression of another type. An alternative is
       to use the envelope/letter pattern:
         http://users.rcn.com/jcoplien/Patterns/C++Idioms/EuroPLoP98.html#EnvelopeLetter
         http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Envelope_Letter
     */
    simplify():Expression { return this }
}

ConstantExpr < SimpleExpr {
    isConstant:Boolean = true
}

VariableExpr < SimpleExpr {
    isConstant:Boolean = false
}

CompoundExpr < Expression {
    operation:Token
    children:Expression[]

    commutesWith(op:Expression):Boolean
    isCommutative:Boolean
    isConstant:Boolean = (){ 
        for each child in this.children:
            if not child.isConstant, return false
        return true
    }
    simplify():Expression {
        for each child& in this.children {
            child = child.simplify()
        }
        return this.simplify_node()
    }
    simplify_node(): Expression {
        if this.isConstant {
            evaluate this, returning new ConstExpr
        } else {
            if one child is simple {
                if this.commutesWith(compound child)
                   and one grand-child doesn't match the constness of the simple child 
                   and the other grand-child matches the constness of the simple child 
                {
                    if (compound child.isCommutative):
                        make odd-man-out among grand-children the outer child
                    rotate so that grand-children are both const or not
                    if grand-children are const:
                        set compound child to compound child.simplify_node()
                    }
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
        return this
    }
}
```

The PHP implementation for `SimpleExpr` and `ConstantExpr`, for example, could be:

```
class SimpleExpr extends Expression {
    public $value;
    function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
    function simplify() { 
        return $this;
    }
}

class ConstantExpr extends SimpleExpr {
    // Overloading
    function __get($name) {
        switch ($name) {
        case 'isConstant':
            return True;
        }
    }
}
```

An alternate implementation of `ConstantExpr`:

```
function Expression {
    protected $_properties = array();
    // Overloading
    function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->_properties[$name])) {
            return $this->_properties[$name]; 
        } else {
            // handle undefined property
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}

class ConstantExpr extends SimpleExpr {
    function __construct($value) {
        parent::construct($value);
        $this->_properties['isConstant'] = True;
    }
}
```

Comment: If that works, then thank you very much!

Do you know any place I can learn about what you described here? I don't know more about OOP that making classes, objects and calling them...

Comment: @50ndr33: I have no particular references. A web search would serve you just as well, as long as you don't limit yourself to PHP. That is, look for OO examples of expression trees in any programming language.

Comment: I understood the point here, but do you suggest that I learn OOP and use pre-made classes to modify the equation?

Comment: So, expression trees is a common way to deal with mathematical formulas? In terms of telling PHP which operator (+-*/) to use with the different values?

Comment: I couldn't find too much about the subject on Google that was about PHP. I don't know C#, so it's a bit hard to follow them.

Comment: @50ndr33: expression trees are pretty much *the* way to deal with mathematical formula, programs and any form of computation. The only times you wouldn't need expression trees is if you're evaluating the expression immediately.

Comment: Thanks, but will it be possible to make the script output the steps for simplifying the equation (and eventually solve it)? Like this: +3*x+1=+3^(+2)+2*(3+2). Take (3+2) and add to get (5), remove the brackets to get 5. Look at 2*5, multiply them to get 10. Look at 3^(+2). This means 3*3 which is 9. Look at 9+10 is 19. Look at +1 on the left side. Move it over to get 19-1 which is 18. On the left side we have 3x. Divide by 3 on all the terms to get 3x/3 = 18/3 which is x = 6. The answer is x = 6.

Comment: Because I didn't understand much practically, only the idea of the expression tree. Therefore I don't want to learn all that before I have practiced and mastered arrays and that psuedo stuff, if it isn't possible to make the script output the steps anyway.

Comment: @50ndr33: all this should be in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5167/discussion-between-outis-and-50ndr33). Comments aren't meant for discussions.

Comment: Hi! Do you want to continue the chat tomorrow, or are you busy? If not, which time can we chat? :)

Comment: @50ndr33: this is a busy week for me. Rather than a realtime chat, we can try a longchat, where we don't wait for the other person to join the chat room before replying. Review the ["For the next time:"](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1916481#1916481) section (note the [correction](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1956351#1956351) at the bottom) and post any questions you have about it; I'll respond when I have the chance.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive foreach function, from comments at: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
/* Grab any values from a multidimensional array using infinite recursion.  --Kris */
function RecurseArray($inarray, $result) {
    foreach ($inarray as $inkey => $inval) {
        if (is_array($inval)) {
            $result = RecurseArray($inval, $result);
        } else {
            $result[] = $inval;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Note that the above implementation produces a flattened array. To preserve nesting:

```
function RecurseArray($inarray) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ( $inarray as $inkey => $inval ) {
        if ( is_array($inval) ) {
            $result[] = RecurseArray($inval);
        } else {
            // process $inval, store in result array
            $result[] = $inval;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

To modify an array in-place:

```
function RecurseArray(&$inarray) {
    foreach ( $inarray as $inkey => &$inval ) {
        if ( is_array($inval) ) {
            RecurseArray($inval);
        } else {
            // process $inval
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this` only exists in methods.

Comment: @50ndr33: this is simply a skeletal illustration of a function that recurses over arrays.

Comment: @50ndr33 exactly what outis said.  This is the structure to infinitely go deeper into each array, as you said was the need.  Add your processing in here and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I understand it like this: It goes into the sub-array, and if the value of the sub-array is an array it goes into that sub-sub-array and so on. When we're in the innermost, it will go to else {} so I can process the equation. But it will always go into the first. So if I have (keys seperated with dots): 1.3.4.2.3 and 1.3.3, then this will find only 1.3.3? So when it has completely removed the brackets and the array, I can run this again to find 1.3.4.2.3? And then it'll find 1.3.4.2.4 if that exists?

Comment: @50ndr33: it simply visits every element of every array, including the arrays that are themselves elements of arrays. It "finds" everything. Use an interactive debugger to see more precisely what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the following code and let me know the results.

You just need to pass your array to the `find_deepest` function.

```
function find_deepest( $array )
{
    $index       = '';        // this variable stores the current position (1.2, 1.3.2, etc.)
    $include     = true;      // this variable indicates if the current position should be added in the result or not
    $result      = array();   // this is the result of the function, containing the deepest indexes
    $array_stack = array();   // this is a STACK (or LIFO) to temporarily store the sub-arrays - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29
    reset( $array );          // here we make the array internal POINTER move to the first position

    // each loop interaction moves the $array internal pointer one step forward - see http://php.net/each
    // if $current value is null, we reached the end of $array; in this case, we will also continue the loop, if the stack contains more than one array
    while ( ( $current = each( $array ) ) || ( count( $array_stack ) > 1 ) )
    {
        // we are looping $array elements... if we find an array (a sub-array), then we will "enter it...
        if ( is_array( $current['value'] ) )
        {
            // update the index string
            $index .= ( empty ( $index ) ? '' : '.' ) . $current['key'];
            // we are entering a sub-array; by default, we will include it
            $include = true;
            // we will store our current $array in the stack, so we can move BACK to it later
            array_push( $array_stack, $array );
            // ATTENTION! Here we CHANGE the $array we are looping; here we "enter" the sub-array!
            // with the command below, we start to LOOP the sub-array (whichever level it is)
            $array = $current['value'];
        }
        // this condition means we reached the END of a sub-array (because in this case "each()" function has returned NULL)
        // we will "move out" of it; we will return to the previous level
        elseif ( empty( $current ) )
        {
            // if we reached this point and $include is still true, it means that the current array has NO sub-arrays inside it (otherwise, $include would be false, due to the following lines)
            if ( $include )
                $result[] = $index;
            // ATTENTION! With the command below, we RESTORE $array to its precedent level... we entered a sub-array before, now we are goin OUT the sub-array and returning to the previous level, where the interrupted loop will continue
            $array = array_pop( $array_stack );
            // doing the same thing with the $index string (returning one level UP)
            $index = substr( $index, 0, strrpos( $index, '.' ) );
            // if we are RETURNING one level up, so we do NOT want the precedent array to be included in the results... do we?
            $include = false;
        }
        // try removing the comment from the following two lines! you will see the array contents, because we always enter this "else" if we are not entering a sub-array or moving out of it
        // else
        //   echo $index . ' => ' . $current['value'] . '<br>';
    }
    return $result;
}

$result = find_deepest( $my_array );
print_r( $result );
```

The most important parts of the code are:

1. the `each` command inside the `while` loop
2. the `array_push` function call, where we store the current array in the "array stack" in order to return back to it later
3. the `array_pop` function call, where we return one level back by restoring the current array from the "array stack"

Comment: `is_array($item)` should never be true in this context, since `array_walk_recursive()` will not call the function if the value is an array. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: I tried it. Here is the code I used: Too much. Written in the question.

Comment: @50ndr33 I have completely changed my answer. The code is ready to use. Please, try, and let me know if it works. I have tested it with success.

Comment: @jli You are right. I have spent a bit of time coding, and reached a fully working solution for 50ndr33 problem. My answer has been completely changed.

Comment: I see that you use & before array_pop (&array_pop) and array_push( $array_stack, &$array) What does it do?

And it worked! :D Hundreds of millions of thanks! Here's the output; 
( ! ) Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 50
Array ( [0] => 1.3.2 [1] => 1.3.4 [2] => 1.4 )  Do you have any idea of what that "error" is?

Comment: When I remove the &'s the error disappears. Are they essential?

Comment: Thank you very very much! But, can you add some comments to show how to code works. I just barely don't bear with your script there..

Comment: @50ndr33 It seems you can safely remove the `&` symbol. I will update the answer. I will also try to add a few explanations about the code. Hopefully, it will became the accepter answer... :-)

Comment: Good illustration of how to manually implement recursion, but unnecessary. The function call stack will take care of all that. @50ndr33: a quick Google search would have lead you to [Passing by Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and [References Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Comment: @outis Actually, I did try this technique, but I didn't seem to work out a solution..

Comment: @outis IMO, the recursive function is unnecessary. It's just a different point of view...

Comment: @50ndr33 Did I answer your question?

Comment: The code is clean/simple... it is now full of comments, as requested by question author.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem, but I got in contact with Outis, and he has learned me much about the teory behind his method of using expresson trees. So I don't know yet what to do...

Answer (score 1):

`RecursiveIteratorIterator` knows the current depth of any children. As you're interested only in children that have children, filter those with no children out and look for max-depth.

Then filter again based by depth for max-depth:

```
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$cf = new ChildrenFilter($ritit);

$maxdepth = NULL;
foreach($cf as $v)
{
    $maxdepth = max($maxdepth, $cf->getDepth());
}

if (NULL === $maxdepth)
{
    throw new Exception('No children found.');
}

$df = new DepthFilter($cf, $maxdepth);

foreach($df as $v)
{
    echo "Array with highest depth:\n", var_dump($v), "\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JNVAg1.php53_t) / [Source](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JNVAg1)

Comment: What about arrays without subarrays that aren't at the maximum depth?

Comment: What should be about those? I mean you didn't ask for them, but you can use the `DepthFilter` on lower depths, too.

Comment: Assuming what 50ndr33 actually wants to do is simplify an expression, the optimizer would need to find more leaf arrays than just the deepest. `ChildrenFilter` may be sufficient, depending on exactly what it selects.

Comment: I only know the very basics about OOP and don't know anything about pre-made classes. So if anyone could explain what is happening here, I would really appreciate that :)

Comment: That are iterators, provided by SPL: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2008/08/06/5-great-articles-on-spl-iterators/

Comment: Note that `ChildrenFilter` and `DepthFilter` aren't part of the SPL. See the [PHP SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) manual page for the primary documentation.