# Can Anyone Explain ?: in regular expression

Tags: regex, tcl

TCL: Can Anyone Explain ?: in regular expression

I am getting confusion between ? and ?: .

? means preceding character may or may not be present.

Then I am not understanding what (?:) indicates.

Can Anyone please Explain this.

```
([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)
```

Comment: `?` has lots of special uses in regular expressions, its meaning depends on what's to the left of it. These meanings are often unrelated to each other.

Comment: Well, `(?` has a lot of meanings depending on the next 1-2 characters.

Comment: @chx : what are the possible characters to change the meaning else than : in (?:)

Comment: I don't think I can possibly list all of them, look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html for a ton of possibilities: modifiers for subexpressions, lookaheads, conditionals, then subroutines as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941259/pcre-regular-expressions-using-named-pattern-subroutines described here.

Answer (score 27):

Suppose, you were trying to look for something like `ABC123` or `ABC123.45` in your input String and you wanted to capture the letters and the numbers separately. You would use a regex (a bit similar to yours) like

```
([A-Z]+)([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)
```

The above regex would match `ABC123.45` and provide three groups as well that represent sub-parts of the whole match and are decided by where you put those `()` brackets. So, given our regex (without using `?:`) we got

```
Group 1 = ABC
Group 2 = 123.45
Group 3 = .45
```

Now, it may not make much sense to capture the decimal portion always and it actually  has already been captured in our Group 2 as well. So, how would you make that group `()` non capturing? Yes, by using `?:` at the start as

```
([A-Z]+)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)
```

Now, you only get the two desired groups

```
Group 1 = ABC
Group 2 = 123.45
```

Notice, I also changed the last part of the regex from `\.[0-9]*` to `\.[0-9]+`. This would prevent a match on `123.` i.e. numbers without a decimal part but still having a dot.

Answer (score 3):

`?:` just doesn't create a capturing group. For example `a(?:b)` will match the "ab" in "abc"

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [re_syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M16) manual page from the Tcl documentation, the `?:` within a parenthetical group turns off the capturing of that group. In other words the expression `(\d)(\d)` would match 2 digits and make each one available in a separate match group. The expression `(\d)(?:\d)` is similar but does not provide the matches in separate match groups. Specifically for tcl:

```
regexp {(\d)(\d)} $data -> first second
```

will make the first digit and second digits available in the named variables. The corresponding non-collecting regular expression will no provide 3 results but only 1 for the single match from the target. So your expression has 2 outputs one for everything matched and one for the outermost parentheses. The inner parentheses make a regexp group but avoid producing another matching output. So you have something that matches a decimal (3.1415, 0., 10)

Comment: This (?:) syntax is only for TCL or it can be any language that uses Regular Expression ?

Comment: It(?:) can be used in other languages as well.!!!

Comment: @user2742564 It's not universal, but it's extremely common among the advanced RE engines.