# Regex with lookaround for Lazarus

Tags: regex, pascal, lazarus

I am looking for a regex engine for Lazarus that supports lookahead and lookbehind (and utf8 matching, if possible). I am aware of and use TRegExpr, but it apparently doesn't support lookahead/behind (though I haven't found anything in documentation that explicitly states it; only tested it unsuccessfully). I am also aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282749/best-delphi-regex-library), which concerns Delphi. I am not sure which can and cannot be used in Lazarus. Any ideas?

Comment: You should consider using a parser rather than complicated regex. See [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html), and [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) before you start, and [Making Regexes Maintanable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764247/why-are-regular-expressions-so-controversial/4053506#4053506) if you're going for it.