# Regex Get Email handle from Email Address

Tags: php, regex, email

I have an email address that could either be
`$email = "x@example.com";` or `$email="Johnny <x@example.com>"`
I want to get 
`$handle = "x";` for either version of the $email.
How can this be done in PHP (assuming regex). I'm not so good at regex.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that (assuming the email address you're working with is coming from the "From:" line of an RFC2822 mail message, or equivalent), it's perfectly possible to have an address with @'s or angle brackets quoted inside the display name. For example: `"Johnny @ home" <x@example.com>`

Comment: David's right.  None of the answers below will cover the entire range of valid email addresses.  It's a reasonably hard problem, and to do it right will probably require a parser, not a regex.  But marcog's solution will catch some 97% of cases (give or take), and that may be good enough for your needs.

Comment: this is really not an issue but, thank you for pointing that out. Username@myservice.com will be the email, and if it's something weird, then we'll just toss it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the regex `<?([^<]+?)@` then get the result from `$matches[1]`.

Here's what it does:

- `<?` matches an optional `<`.
- `[^<]+?` does a non-greedy match of one or more characters that are not `^` or `<`.
- `@` matches the `@` in the email address.

A non-greedy match makes the resulting match the shortest necessary for the regex to match. This prevents running past the `@`.

Rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/bntNa8YVZt

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete PHP solution based on marcog's answer

```
function extract_email($email_string) {
    preg_match("/<?([^<]+?)@([^>]+?)>?$/", $email_string, $matches);
    return $matches[1] . "@" . $matches[2];
}

echo extract_email("ice.cream.bob@gmail.com"); // outputs ice.cream.bob@gmail.com
echo extract_email("Ice Cream Bob <ice.cream.bob@gmail.com>"); // outputs ice.cream.bob@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search the string using this basic email-finding regex: \b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
It will match any email in any text, and in your first string it will match the whole string, and in the second, only the part of the string that is e-mail.

To quickly learn regexp this is the best place: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: Correctly matching email addresses with a regex is a LOT harder than that. (For example, not all top-level domain names are 2-4 characters long, and this regex disallows many valid characters in the local-part of the address.) Many other questions like this, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611775/regular-expression-for-valid-email-address

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = 'x@gmail.com';
preg_match('/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\+]+@[a-z0-9A-Z\-\._]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)/', $email, $regex);
$handle = array_shift(explode('@', $regex[1]));
```

Try that (Not tested)